# Displaying recycler view items one by one instead of all after loading

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have a list with multiple objects and a custom adapter.

```
ExampleAdapter adapter = new ExampleAdapter((ArrayList<MatchItem>) outputList, GamesActivity.this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The problem is that the recycler view is displayed after all the views, for every item in the list are done, but I want to display every item as soon as it is loaded.

I am not sure if I have to create the adapter so it takes as parameter only one item at a time and update the data after every item added.

I am populating the list in an async task and set the adapter in the post execute method

Comment: you can set the `outputlist` empty in the begining on your adapter initialization. And then you can add item one by one to that list, if the item not show up to the recycler view, you can call `adapter.notifyDatasetChange()` every item you add to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing list to the constructor of the adapter, try to add a method in the adapter that accepts one item at a time and then populates the list in the adapter:

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends......{

private List< MatchItem > list = new ArrayList<MatchItem>();

public ExampleAdapter(GamesActivity.this){


}

//this method will accept items one by one
public void addNewItem(MatchItem item){

list.add(item);

this.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

}
```

**And start passing items one by one when the item is ready**

```
//put these as a one time thing
ExampleAdapter adapter = new ExampleAdapter(GamesActivity.this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

//when you read items
adapter.addNewItem(item);
```

Comment: Thanks but how would the adapter "see" the list if I don't give it as parameter ?

Comment: initially it would be empty, the list is already defined as a member variable of the `adapter`, then items are added one by one using the `addNewItem()`

Comment: Ok, I have a list in the adapter, but I have to give it objects one by one, how do I give the adapter items?
I'm sorry but I still dont understand

Comment: when you give the objects to the adapter they get added to the list, and calling notifyDataSetChanged() it will reload the recyclerview.

Comment: so instead of giving a full list to the adapter, you add them one by one.

Comment: The best solution was to notifi dataset changed in the on progress method from the async task